# Formatting, Big Decimal, interest to percent please

Tags: java, currency, number-formatting, bigdecimal

Can someone please explain the usage not just answer I really would like to learn how to do this. This is my 2nd month using Java and please explain formatting usage in Java. Thank you so much. I really appreciate it. Feel free to ask any other question in regards C++ or python. I am in need of help in formatting, big decimal usage and how to set

```
import java.util.*;

import java.math.BigDecimal;

import java.text.NumberFormat;

import java.math.*;


public class Main{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {

        Scanner myCalculation = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.print("Welcome to the Interest Calculator \n\n");
        String option = "y";
        while (option.equalsIgnoreCase("y"))
        {

            System.out.print("Enter Loan Amount: ");
            //double loanAmount = 520000;
            double loanAmount = myCalculation.nextDouble();
            //Get Interest rate from user
            System.out.print("Enter Interest Rate: ");
            // double interRate = .05375;
            double interRate = myCalculation.nextDouble();


            double interest = loanAmount * interRate;

            System.out.printf("%.3f", interest);
            System.out.println();


            //prompt user to continue? if he enter y then it will Continue
            //else it will stop
            //System.out.println("Continue? (y:n): ");
            Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
            boolean stop = false;    
            while(!stop) {
            //do whatever
                System.out.println("Would you like to continue? (yes or no)");
                String s = scan.nextLine();
                if(s.equals("no")) {
                    stop = true;
                }
            }

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: It isn't clear to me what the question is

Comment: I am trying to calculate the interest amount by using the BigDecimal class to make sure that all calculations are accurate. Then I want to Format the interest rate, interest amount and loan amount and interest by using the NumberFormat abstract class base class.

Comment: I'm going to assume this code won't be used on real money. If you do want to use this on real money, please use a library explicitly built for handling money calculations.

Comment: `NumberFormat` isn't actually abstract, but it _is_ the base class of  `DecimalFormat` ([`javadoc`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/text/DecimalFormat.html)), which you probably will want to use because it can format percentages.

Comment: would you mind please sharing how to use the NumberFormat function

Comment: Hi @Omar - welcome to StackOverflow. It's not entirely clear what you're looking for help with, since there seems to be multiple questions. It might be clearer/easier for others to help if you can break this down into separate posts where each one asks a separate clear question - see https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic an https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: @KevinHooke I am in need of help on how to Format the interest rate, interest amount and loan amount and interest by using the NumberFormat abstract base class

Comment: What do the JavaDocs for NumberFormat tell you? What have you tried so far? If you show what you've tried so far and what's not working, then we can help when you get stuck.

Comment: Also, if you search here for similar questions using keywords like 'java decimal number format' you'll find lots of similar questions with many answers that should help you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
System.out.print("enter double");
double d = in.nextDouble(); //doubles
System.out.print("enter int");
int i = in.nextInt(); //ints

System.out.print("enter text");
String text = in.next(); //gets a string up to the first space
in.nextLine();
System.out.print("enter text w/ spaces");
String line = in.nextLine(); //gets a string up to the first space

System.out.println(d);
System.out.println(i);
System.out.println(text);
System.out.println(line);
in.close();

System.out.println(new DecimalFormat("#.###").format(4.567346344634));
```